# Solving $\operatorname{argmin}_\alpha \|I-\alpha \operatorname{diag} h + 2 \alpha^2 \operatorname{diag} h^2 +\alpha^2 h\otimes h\|$

Tags: linear-algebra, probability, semidefinite-programming

Suppose $h^*=\left(1,\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{3},\ldots,\frac{1}{d}\right)$ and $h=h^*/\|h^*\|_1$.

Can someone see a way to approximate the following quantity for $d\approx 10^6$? The problem is to minimize the norm of a symmetric diagonal+rank1 matrix:

$$\operatorname{argmin}_\alpha \|I-\alpha \operatorname{diag} h + 2 \alpha^2 (\operatorname{diag} h)^2 +\alpha^2 (h\otimes h)\|$$

For $d=2000$ I can [compute it](https://www.wolframcloud.com/obj/yaroslavvb/nn-linear/forum-l2-optimal-step.nb) using brute-force to be $\approx 1.48$ and the hypothesis is that it goes to $2$ as $d\to\infty$

Motivation: this gives optimal step size for SGD used to solve $0=wx_i$ where $x_i$ are drawn from Gaussian with eigenvalues $h$.

Comment: are you using the $2$-norm for the matrix ? also, is $\text{diag } h^2$ meant to be $(\text{diag } h)^2$

Comment: Added some parentheses. Yes, using 2-norm ($\|\cdot\|$ typically refers to the operator norm, which is the same as 2-norm in this case)

Comment: have you tried finding the eigenvalues since the operator norm is the maximal eigenvalue for symmetric matrix ? This is rank 1 update of a diagonal matrix and technically you can get a closed formula for the characteristic equation using the matrix determinant lemma or something similar.

Comment: If there were a simple formula for the largest eigenvalue in terms of $\alpha$, that would make it easy. I have not found one however